# Is it fine to delete my answer and post new one in case I did something wrong, but due to fast downvoters I had no time to edit it?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, answers

I have met few problems when answering.

My scenario:

- I answer question
- I'm testing some better solutions
- I'm just about to edit it because I know my first answer was wrong and it should be improved
- There are at least 3 downvotes

Am I able/Is it fine to delete my old answer (because I'm pretty sure there wouldn't be downvoters monitoring my answer to watch if they could remove their downvote after edit) and create new one?

Comment: A downvote on this question would probably mean: "I don't think you should do that".

Comment: Someone who has asked 41 question on Meta in 58 days should probably understand upvotes/downvotes by now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My experience has been that once you fix the problem, you get a number of upvoters who bring it up to at or above 0.

In other words, you get a lot more rep by being downvoted, fixing it, then upvoted than you would by deleting it and starting a new one.

I'm not a big fan of getting rid of downvotes by deleting an answer and adding a new one, but the system allows it, awards a badge for it (peer pressure), and the whole reason to contribute to the site is to provide high quality answers to problems, so in the long run it won't matter.

I suggest you simply update the answer and see what happens.  It might surprise you.

Answer (score 23):

Don't post bad answers that you only think through afterwards.  Do the prep work beforehand.

Comment: **Do the prep work beforehand.** -- this is something many people forget. We don't want the fastest answers, we want the best.

Comment: It's also a tautology, you cannot do prep work afterwards.