# Is it acceptable to delete downvoted answer and add new one?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it fine to delete my answer and post new one in case I did something wrong, but due to fast downvoters I had no time to edit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102277/is-it-fine-to-delete-my-answer-and-post-new-one-in-case-i-did-something-wrong-b)

I am not doing this. I just realized that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491243/john-woo?tab=answers&sort=newest) do like this. I am asking because I downvoted his more than two answers which was wrong or duplicate and he deleted it and added new one (of course better than older.). See [this question where that user deleted duplicate and downvoted answer and added new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366390/how-to-select-product-that-have-the-maximum-price-of-each-category)

My question: Is it okay to delete downvoted (and wrong) answer and add new (and improved) answer? Or should we edit the downvoted answer?

Comment: This might be a dupe of [Is it fine to delete my answer and post new one in case I did something wrong, but due to fast downvoters I had no time to edit it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102277/176533) (although the question is from 2011, so I'm not sure if new questions/policies came out).

Comment: @Alenanno: I'd say it's a dupe, yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it is. Now should I delete this question or vote to close it?

Comment: @hims056: People are already voting on it to mark it as a duplicate. Just let that run it's course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters By the way I can also vote to close it.

Comment: @hims056: Sure, but I don't think it is necessary. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think **it is better to edit and improve the answer**, but I don't think deleting the answer and writing a new one is wrong either. When deleting and writing a new one you are correcting your error too.

The thing is that if you edit you are keeping the negative votes afecting to the score, unless users who voted negative remove the negative votes (which not always happens and should). This  is probably the reason why this user prefers to delete and answer again.

Comment: It depends on how wrong the answer is. If there's a minor error, correct it by editing. If it's a major problem then deletion and posting a new answer is probably the best option.