# Deleting downvoted answers to shed down-votes and then posting higher quality content?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, down-votes, deleted-answers

I see that this has been marked as a duplicate, I don't think it is a duplicate, the linked question is about deleting down-voted answers for the purpose of removing negative reputation. *This* question is about deleting the answer to shed the down-vote and then posting higher quality content.

It seems as people are voting their agreement or disagreement here. Let me encourage voters to consider the value of

- this discussion
- the transparency of the poster

### The drama:

Questioner explained what they were doing, and inquired about an error.

No one else had responded, so I quickly pulled up the help on the function as I saw it used and quickly typed a one-liner to explain the source of the error. I begin furiously editing/elaborating as I see another answer pop up, offering an alternative and I see a downvote on my answer. Spirit undiminished, I continued, explaining how to check for the source of the error, and thus how to avoid it. I edited further, I demonstrated how to recreate the error.

I then see the other answerer has identically adopted my approach to his mishmash, and although I don't have a monopoly on Python's best practices, a bit of attribution/credit would be apropos.

### An Underhanded Move:

Feeling now quite frustrated with the effort I have spent, I perceive a way to overturn the single downvote **(on what was now substantially an entirely different answer)**. I copy the source of my answer, delete the old answer, and paste it in as a new one.

### The End Result:

I see as I have composed this I have earned an upvote on my full answer, although the other respondent got the best of me with an accepted answer. If the upvote came from the original downvoter, then I am no better for the deletion and replacement. If the upvote came from someone else, I am better for the deletion, for I would otherwise be at zero and down 2 rep points.

### The Final Question:

Was I right to act as I did, in principle? If not, do circumstances mitigate the harm? Or is the point infinitesimal, and I would be better off trying to fit angels on the heads of pins, and Stack Overflow is working just as it should? Or perhaps we just don't want to talk transparently about how people abuse the system to their advantage?

### A Final Conclusion After Many Responses:

The community has decided that although the Stack Overflow mechanisms allow for this tactic, it is viewed as underhanded and abusive, and a user being found to do so is likely to be punished, if not officially, then by the efforts of those who have discovered him.

Comment: _"quickly typed a one-liner"_ -- this naturally involves risk of down votes and "fastest gun" answerers should be ready to accept that risk (FWIW I upvoted your question but this reasoning might explain down votes)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not a fan of this move at all.

Here's what it distills to:

- You answered a question
- You got a downvote on your answer
- You edited your answer *in hopes of redeeming that downvote*
- You deleted said answer **and reposted the same answer**, ***just to get the upvote***.

There was no abuse of the system (from other actors.  You, however, aren't exempt from blame).

There was no harm.

Stack Overflow is working as intended. Someone saw fit to disagree with the usefulness of your answer, and responded accordingly.

Downvotes happen.  Most of us have had their fair share (and a few that were unjustly deserved, in some cases).  But, by no means does that make it okay to **completely remove an answer** that still has a chance of helping someone else out there, just because it was downvoted.

Comment: Actually, I am wondering about the results of this action: he got an upvote after he "resetted" the score- that would show that given the same contents we are more inclined to upvote answers that have no downvotes. Basically, do we "follow the pack": +1 calls for more +1, -1 calls for more -1? Not the same question as above but something to reflect on anyway.

Answer (score 23):

You were wrong.

1. You are complaining about a vote on a post you made
2. Rather than accepting that you deserved the downvote, you did your best to avoid it
3. Despite understanding why you got the downvote, you created a question solely to complain about it

**Bonus:** You even spitefully downvoted <s>two</s> three people who provided answers because they don't agree with you.

### You Made the Post

And I quote:

> so I quickly pulled up the help on the function as I saw it used and quickly typed a one-liner to explain the source of the error.

You got a downvote because a one-liner pulled from the help doesn't exactly solve the problem, now does it? Hover over the 'downvote' button, what does it say?

> [image: Downvote Message]

*"This answer is not useful"*

Why are you complaining that a post you made, that you concede was not useful and required several rounds of editing, received a downvote?

### You Didn't Accept It

Despite the rather clear fact that the downvote was entirely merited on the basis of your original answer, you refused to acknowledge that you deserve the hit to your reputation.

A downvote is worth -2 reputation. A single upvote is worth +10.

If your answer would eventually get a single upvote, you'd be at +8. And the person who had made the downvote would have a chance to turn that -2 in to a +10. Instead you delete the original answer based on your sense of justice ignoring that it was merited in the first place based on what you had posted and could be changed in the future.

### You Asked Here About It

From [your responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217042/deleting-downvoted-answers-to-recover-votes-and-reputation-while-re-posting-the#comment703188_217043) to people here it is clear you think your action was justified:

> Let's not say, as a community, we're a site based on gamification and then complain that someone breaks rules that are not written down or enforced.

You brought this up. We as a community are telling you that your action is wrong and you shouldn't have done it. We have explained the concept behind why this is wrong, and linked you to resources you can visit to understand them. These rules are both written down, and if you really want to test the waters, I'm quite certain that you can experience them first hand.

You know what you did is wrong too, [as you said in your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217042/209637):

> Or perhaps we just don't want to talk transparently about how people abuse the system to their advantage?

We don't want people to abuse the system in the first place. You were wrong to do it. Period.

Answer (score 21):

In principle, you should not have taken those actions. You care too much about votes, and you may be here for the wrong reasons.

I'll quote the [Stack Exchange site itself](https://stackexchange.com/):

> We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on the most important topics in each area of expertise. From our core of Q&A, to community blogs and real-time chat, we provide experts with the tools they need to make The Internet a better place.

We are here to make the internet a better place through building libraries of useful information.

You're engaging in behaviour that is either manipulative or undermining the systems Stack Exchange has in place for achieving its mission:

- Deleting and reposting your answers to shed downvotes. It's good you asked here about that.
- Requesting that people upvote this question if they were entertained. That's not the point of upvotes.
- Requesting explanation of downvotes *you know* the reason for is dubious.

It would seem you're more concerned about your votes and reputation, and whether or not others are getting the best of you.

Instead, you should be trying to improve this library of information, and you should be doing so with integrity you are not currently demonstrating.

If your answer gets downvoted, you have lost *two rep total*, and worrying about who cast votes on you is pointless. Accept it, and either wait for further votes or delete your answer if you want to. But if you delete your answer, do so because it improves the quality of information the site offers (or because you want the rep you lost back). Don't do it in order to repost it and entirely evade the votes already cast.

Comment: `Users look at the votes as a heuristic for the quality of the answer.` ?? Not Really..

Answer (score 6):

This is not how Stack Exchange network works. Deleting downvoted answers and adding the same answer is not a good way to use Stack Exchange sites.

We even don't encourage to [delete wrong/poor answer and add another improved one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102279/187824). Instead you should edit the elder one. Don't take downvotes too serious. Take it serious to improve the answer not deleting it and adding another one. If your downvoted answer is good enough, surely future visitors will upvote it if they find helpful.

Also, deleting downvoted answers may send you to [the storm of answer ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/187824).

Answer (score -5):

Just take the final effect of what you have done:

1. You've posted some answer that seemed not to much the quality criteria
2. You've effectively posted new answer, that one correct
3. You've removed the old answer

In the end effect, the SO has one more valuable answer, and has not one more not valuable answer. You could achieve it either by:

1. Leaving original, edited answers, with downvotes from previous content. The downvotes would suggest there's something wrong with your answer. That suggestion would be invalid, because the previous content was downvoted, not the current one.
2. Create new answers. There are no misleading downvotes.

You've chosen the better one, in my opinion. Only the path leading to that effect was not fully corrent, and therefore controversial. It would be better to post new answer and delete the old one, but it's the effect that is the most important. And that effect is positive.